# Find the next number in the series?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Find the value of 'a' and 'b' in the following series.

```
100,101,120,103,410,321,205,404,60a,5b2
```

Comment: may be a = 3 , b=3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sum of all digits in every number is growing.

```
Number     digits SUM
---------------------
100        1
101        2
120        3
103        4
410        5
321        6
205        7
404        8
60a        it should be 9       so "a" = 9-6 = 3
5b2        it should be 10      so "b" = 10-5-2 = 3
```